# How get Lead Id in apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, leads, before-trigger, emailmessage

When sending an email from the lead screen. Is it possible to get the lead id in the before of the EmailMessage trigger?

Answer (score 2):

### For objects other than Lead and Contact

The before trigger on EmailMessage should include a value for `RelatedToId` which is the parent of the email message (e.g., the Opportunity.Id). Your trigger will need to requery to get values from the Opportunity and do so in a bulkified manner.

Note that `EmailMessage.RelatedToId` is polymorphic and not every `EmailMessage` will have an Opportunity as parent. Thus, you'll want code something like

```
for (EmailMessage em: Trigger.new) {
  if (em.RelatedToId.getSobjectType() == Opportunity.SObjectType) {
      // collect the RelatedToIds in a set to query for Opportunities
  }
}

// bulkified query for Leads and put in map<ID,Opportunity>

// second pass through Trigger.new to deal with EmailMessage for Opportunity
```

### For emails sent from Lead or Contact

- the beforeInsert trigger has no value for `RelatedToId`
- the afterInsert trigger has no value for `RelatedToId`
- the afterInsert trigger does have a value for `ActivityId` that points at a Task and the `Task.WhoId` points at the Lead (or Contact).

So, you'll need to use an afterInsert trigger, query (bulkified) all parent Task including their `WhoId` field

```
Set<Id> taskIds = new Set<Id>();
for (EmailMessage em: Trigger.new) {
  taskIds.add(em.ActivityId);
}

Task[] tasks = SELECT 
    TYPEOF Who
       WHEN Contact THEN Id, Email, FirstName, LastName, Account.Name
       WHEN Lead THEN Id, Company, Email
       ELSE Name
    END
    FROM Task WHERE Id IN: taskIds;

 // do something with the Tasks that reference Leads
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I send an email from the lead, the EmailMessage.RelatedToId is null in the before of the EmailMessage trigger. So it didn't work.

Comment: @HenriqueArguto - how are you sending the email from the Lead - via quick action? from the Activity related list? from feed-based layout?

Comment: Hi, @cropredy. I use a feed-based layout

Comment: @HenriqueArguto -- updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But the idea was to check the recordType of the lead and change the From. Before sending the email.

Comment: @cropedy Taking advantage I wanted to take another doubt https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311436/how-to-change-the-from-the-emailmessage-before-sending-the-email-via-apex

Comment: well, my example shows how to get the Lead, you can then do what you want to the EmailMessage associated to the Task w/ parent Lead

Comment: So the problem is that I cannot change the "ValidatedFromAddress" after the EmailMessage. Thank you very much.  @cropedy