# How to change the From the emailmessage before sending the email via apex?

Tags: apex, trigger, emailmessage

When I change the ValidatedFromAddress in the before the emailmessage trigger it goes back to the user's email. The email received comes from the user and not from the changed email. Can you tell me why? I'm sent through the lead feed.

Example:

```
trigger EmailMessage on EmailMessage (before insert, after insert) {
    
    system.debug('**: '+ JSON.serializePretty(Trigger.new));
    
    if( Trigger.isBefore ){
        for(EmailMessage em : Trigger.new ){
            em.ValidatedFromAddress = 'email2@test.com.br';
            em.FromAddress = 'email2@test.com.br';
        }
    }
}
```

The email "email2@test.com.br" is registered with the organization and validated.
When I receive the email it comes from the user's email address and not "email2@test.com.br"

Comment: please use [edit] to show your code; also note `FromAddress` and `EmailMessageRelation` as per https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm

Comment: @cropredy  updated question